# How to solve this query to find difference?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an employee relation with attributes such as `(emp_id,emp_name,salary)` and I want to find the difference between salary and average salary of each employee. I'm using SQL Plus.

i.e. `salary-avg(salary)` of each

Comment: Please show the query you have attempted, and tell us which version of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT a.emp_id,
       a.emp_name,
       a.salary,
       a.Designation,
      (a.salary - b.salary) as salary_difference 
FROM employee AS a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Designation, avg(salary) as salary
  from employee
  group by Designation) as b
ON a.Designation = b.Designation ;
```

<kbd>[**SQL Fiddle HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/728737/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a window function:

```
SELECT emp_id,
       emp_name,
       salary
       salary - avg(salary) over () as diff
FROM employee
```